# mint.com programming technology

Tags: programming-languages

Does anyone know what's [mint.com](http://www.mint.com)'s programming language/technology? Are they using Java? .NET? Python? Ruby?

Their site is extremely good and I was just wondering what they've chosen to develop their web site.

Thanks.

P.S. MINT.COM is a Personal Finance Management online application.
P.S. 2: THANKS EVERYONE FOR ANSWERING. I really found every single answer very helpful. Also I am happy I found out about Matt's blog.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a job posting for mint.com, this might give some idea about the technology they're using:

http://mint.jobscore.com/jobs/mint/softwareengineerfulltime/c1owZqeQOr3OM4aaWP50_m

Looks like:

- Linux or Unix server
- Java
- Hibernate
- MySql database

Answer (score 10):

I'd guess Java

Their front-end marketing site is 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9

But the login page is powered by
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

[Coyote](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/coyote.html) is used with Java-based systems.

Answer (score 6):

I guess Java, by looking at the job openings.

Answer (score 5):

"Looks extremely good" part I guess comes from [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) based on [Matt's](http://mattsnider.com/) blog .
There are also some very nice snippets and samples on his blog that are used on mint.com.

Comment: Yeah, and they do a lot of flash as well for the graphs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing they're not using .net as their servers are all running F5 Big-IP or CentOS. [Here](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.mint.com)'s the Netcraft report. But it's hard to say what their service is developed on--though job openings are certainly one potential indicator.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Wikipedia article about the founder Aaron Patzer, the alpha version was built with J2EE and mySQL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Patzer